# Iterating over excel sheets and create one dataframe

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, data-structures

I am trying to iterate over several excel sheets and fetch particular information (column named "Value" from each sheet) into a single DataFrame object.

I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel("file / path", sheet_name=None)
```

df is then fetched as OrderedDict and some other data structures within. It looks like that:

```
([('Austria',
                                       Name     Value
 0     3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global CHF R T    5
 1     3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global R T        6
 [2 rows x 2 columns]),

('Belgium',
                                       Name     Value
 0      AG Life Alternative Investments           7
 1      AG Life Balanced                          1
 2      AG Life Bonds Global                      2
 3      AG Life Bonds Indexed                     7
 [4 rows x 2 columns])])
```

The problem is that I don't know how to proceed further with decomposing and inspecting the elements in this data structure. I want ultimately to create a DataFrame having just the "Value" from the above data structure. The names of the columns might be any; it would be best if they are the country names. It would look like that:

```
   Austria   Belgium
0     5         7
1     6         1
2     NaN       2
3     NaN       7
```